# I'm unable to remove my NullPointerException error

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception

The below code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Enter your value : ")
    try{
        val(a, b, c) = readLine()!!.split(' ')
        println("Values are $a $b and $c")
    }catch(ex : IndexOutOfBoundsException){
        println("Invalid. Missing values")
    }
}
```

produces the following error in Kotlin Playground:

```
Enter your value:
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException at FileKt.main(File.kt:4)
```

I have seen other questions with NullPointerException but I am unable to resolve it. I might would have missed some so it would be really helpful if you can share useful links. Since I am new to Kotlin, it would be awesome if you correct my program.

Remark: I don't have any background on java either and most of the NullPointerException questions are based on java

**Edit 1** : *I have tried gidds' solution and it seems to be working except one minor fault. The readLine() is for some reason not working.*

*The below code*

```
fun main(args : Array <String>){
 val line = readLine()
 try{

    println("Output : $line")

    if (line != null) {
        val(a, b, c) = line.split(' ')
        println("Values are $a $b and $c")
    } else {
             println("No values given...")
    }
  }
catch(ex : IndexOutOfBoundsException){
    println("Invalid. Missing Values...")
}
}
```

*produces the following error in Kotlin Playground :*

```
Output : null
No values given...
```

*I guess I was getting the previous errors due to the same reason, i.e. readLine() was not working properly and the user is not getting an opportunity to give input(s).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on the earlier answer, this is about how to handle `null`s.

The problem is that `readLine()` can return `null`.  (This happens if end-of-file is reached; for example, if you redirect the input from a file, and reach the end of the file; or if it's taking input from the keyboard and you press Ctrl+D.)

The Kotlin compiler knows this.  (Nullability is built into Kotlin's type system.  `readLine()` returns a `String?` — the question mark indicates that the value could be `null`.)

Kotlin is very careful about null-safety, and won't let you do anything with the value that would fail if it's `null`.  So in your code, if you omit the `!!`, you get an error on the following `.`.  (‘Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a non-nullable receiver of type String?’)

So you have to handle the `null` somehow.

Appending the [not-null assertion `!!`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator) effectively promises the compiler that you know better, and that it can never be null.  This is usually a bad idea (which is why that operator was designed to look ugly); in practice, you generally *don't* know better than the compiler, and it will trip you up — as you've discovered!  In your case `readLine()` *did* return `null`, and so the `!!` operator threw a `KotlinNullPointerException`.

So, you need a better way to handle it.

The traditional way is an explicit check, e.g.:

```
val line = readLine()
if (line != null) {
    // Within this block, the compiler knows that line
    // cannot be null.
} else {
    println("No values given.")
}
```

This is a good, clear, general approach.  And it may be the best approach in your case.  (You'd still need to catch the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, though.)

Because that approach can be a bit long-winded, Kotlin has some other tools that can be better in particular situations.  I don't think any are appropriate here, but I'll mention some for completeness:

One of those is the [safe-call operator `?.`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) given in the error message and the earlier answer.  This makes the call only if the value is not `null`; otherwise, it returns the `null` directly.  That can be really useful, but it's not a simple answer in this case, as your comment shows: although it avoids trying to `split()` the `null`, you then fail to deconstruct it into the three values `a`, `b`, and `c`.  (After all, `null` is not an array.)

If you wanted to substitute default values for `a`, `b`, and `c` if there was no input, you could use the safe-call operator in conjunction with the [elvis operator `?:`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator).  That returns the left-hand side if it's not `null`, else the right-hand side.  So you could do e.g.:

```
val (a, b, c) = readLine()?.split(' ')
              ?: arrayOf("defA", "defB", "defC")
println("Values are $a, $b, and $c.")
```

In this case, if `readLine()` returns a string, `split()` would be called on it; or if not, it would use the hard-coded array instead.

Note that this still isn't a complete solution, as it won't cope if you enter a line with less than two spaces.  (So you'd still need to catch the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, or check for that case explicitly.)

(Perhaps the shortest solution overall would be to leave the `!!` intact, and change the `catch` block to catch `Exception`, so it would catch the `KotlinNullPointerException` along with the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  I'm not recommending that, as it's ugly: it's not clear to anyone reading the code what could happen and what exceptions you're intending to catch — and it could hide other problems in the code if they also resulted in exceptions.)

Answer (score 1):

With `readLine()!!`, you are saying the compiler that if this returns null, that will crash with NullPointerException. In another way, you must be sure to have return value of `readLine()` to be not null. Read more about `!!` operator [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator).

> The not-null assertion operator (`!!`) converts any value to a non-null
>   type and throws an exception if the value is null.

You can have null check with [elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) like below:

```
try{
    val(a, b, c) = readLine()?.split(' ')
    println("Values are $a $b and $c")
}catch(ex : IndexOutOfBoundsException){
    println("Invalid. Missing values")
}
```

Comment: The above code is showing an error in Kotlin Playground as : -------> {Not nullable value required to call 'component1()' function of destructuring declaration initializer.} ------------------There are 2 more such errors for "component 2" and "component 3".